# Toggle slide button lost position in Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, bootstrap-modal

i'm working on a small project - [here is it](http://plnkr.co/edit/BPDrpGF5EersM4nfGyZX?p=preview)  and i have 2 problems.

1. When playing with the toggle slide buttons - you'll see they are loosing their position, the round dot is staying in it's place while it's border moves. This caused by the text i guess.

The buttons are working fine without datatables.

Here is my css :

```
    .cmn-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -9999px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.cmn-toggle + label {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* ============================================================
  SWITCH 2 - ROUND FLAT
============================================================ */
input.cmn-toggle-round-flat + label {
    padding: 2px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 29px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
    -moz-border-radius: 60px;
    -ms-border-radius: 60px;
    -o-border-radius: 60px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: background 0.4s;
    -o-transition: background 0.4s;
    transition: background 0.4s;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round-flat + label:before, input.cmn-toggle-round-flat + label:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
}
input.cmn-toggle-round-flat + label:before {
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    bottom: 2px;
    right: 2px;
    background-color: #fff;

    -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
    -moz-border-radius: 60px;
    -ms-border-radius: 60px;
    -o-border-radius: 60px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: background 0.4s;
    -o-transition: background 0.4s;
    transition: background 0.4s;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round-flat + label:after {
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #dd0012;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -ms-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-transition: margin 0.4s, background 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: margin 0.4s, background 0.4s;
    -o-transition: margin 0.4s, background 0.4s;
    transition: margin 0.2s, background 0.4s;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round-flat:checked + label {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round-flat:checked + label:after {
    margin-left: 21px;
    background-color: #00e114;
}

.op_name{
  display:inline-flex;
}

.switch{
  display:inline-flex;
}
#example > tbody > tr > td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

2. When clicking on the Edit button  - the modal appears but the content - all the data appears with delay.... iv'e tried removing the "fade" class from the model - and solve the problem - but what if i don't what to lost the fade effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 2. You can try something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtn").click(function(){
        // reference p into modal-body. Here you load all the data
        $("#content").html("The content") 
        $("#myModal").modal(); // finally open the modal
    });
});
```

Or maybe you can fix it using modal evets. Documentation here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events

Hope I helped you.

Comment: Glad to hep! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Solved the first problem by adding

```
`.toggle_btn{
   display: inline-flex;
  }

 .switch{
   margin-left: 85px;
  }
 .op_name{
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 7px;
 }
  `
```